# iPad - "zoomed in" on portrait rotation

Tags: css, ipad

I'm sure this has been asked, but I have not found the answer.

I am using multiple stylesheets for different viewport sizes to target the [iPad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPad) in portrait/landscape view.

When I rotate the iPad, it loads the correct stylesheet for portrait, however it doesn't auto resize to fit to screen correctly. I must zoom out in order for the page to display at full width.

Is there a way to correct for this so that when the iPad rotates between landscape/portrait, it centers the page correctly again?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had the same problem and this metatag solved the problem:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=yes, minimum-scale=0.75, maximum-scale=3.0" />
```

Maybe you'll have to tweak a little to work with your website.

Or head to Apple's documentation, *[Configuring the Viewport](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/UsingtheViewport/UsingtheViewport.html)*.

Comment: By setting minimum scale and maximum scale both to "1.0" it seems to work nicely now. I am not sure if that is what you meant when you said to tweak it a bit but thanks for the help!

Comment: The only problem setting 1.0 for both min and max scale is that you won't be able to scale the viewport.